# UIButton tapped to swap to another xib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton in my MainWindow.xib

When I tap the button, I want to swap the view. How do I do that?

I also want to transfer some data between the views (such as color preference and a string)

ANy sample code OR links to where I can find my answer would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alloc` a temporary view controller, and call `initWithNibName:`. Then call `[self presentModalViewController:(the view controller you just made) animated:YES];` (or NO). To pass data, create a method on your other view controller, add it to its .h file, and then in your .m file for the first view controller, import it and make it a class, and call `[theviewcontrollermadeearlier yourmethod:argument :argument etc.];` e.g.:

MyFirstViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MySecondViewController.h"
...
@class MySecondViewController
...
```

MyFirstViewController.m:

```
...
MySecondViewController *tempVC = [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySecondView"];
[self presentModalViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
[tempVC passDataWithString:@"a string" andColor:yellowcolor];
```

MySecondViewController.h:

```
@interface MySecondViewController : UIViewController {
...
}
- (void)passDataWithString:(NSString *)passedString andColor:(UIColor *)passedColor;
```

MySecondViewController.m:

```
...
- (void)passDataWithString:(NSString *)passedString andColor:(UIColor *)passedColor {
// Do something
}
```

EDIT:
To make the button trigger this, in your first view controller's header file, add `IBOutlet IBAction *buttonPressed;` in the `@interface` section, and then between `}` and `@end` add `- (IBAction)buttonPressed;`
Go into Interface Builder, and connect the `IBAction` to the button.
Then, in your first view controller's main file, add this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {
    // The code to execute when pressed
}
```